# Codeigniter treating array as object in custom class/library

Tags: php, arrays, class, codeigniter

I'm trying to integrate a third-party API (used for interacting with the OpenSecrets.org data) into my Codeigniter site, and keeping getting an error about an object being treated as a string even though the variable is an array.

The original api is available here: https://github.com/bpilkerton/php-crpapi/blob/master/crpapi.php.

My modifications are available here: http://pastebin.com/HmZyhQJR.

I've modified the class so that the filename and class declaration match and both have initial capital letters, and I've modified the constructor so that it only accepts one array of parameters, which are set when the class is called from my controller.

The pertinent section of my modified code is below.  I get errors for the first line of the private function loadParams and the foreach loop in that function.  The first error is:

```
Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string
```

And the second is:

```
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

**Custom class:**

```
class Crp {

function __construct($params) {

    $this->apikey = "a04a90aa18e9e482b3ff2318d313db53";
    $this->baseurl = "http://api.opensecrets.org/";
    $this->output = "json";

    //Allow output type to be overridden on object instantiation
    $this->output = isset($params['output']) ? $params['output']: $this->output;
    $this->method = $params['method'];
    self::loadParams($params);

    /*$this->fileHash = md5($method . "," . implode(",",$params));
    $this->cacheHash = "dataCache/" . $this->fileHash;
    $this->cacheTime = 86400; #one day*/

}

private function loadParams($params) {
    $this->url = $this->baseurl . "?method=" . $this->method .
    "&apikey=" . $this->apikey;

    foreach ($params as $key=>$val) {
        $this->url .= "&" . $key . "=" . $val;
        $this->$key = $val;
    }

    return;
}
```

**And the call in the Controller**

```
$crp_id = $this->_getRefId($id,'indiv','crp');
$this->load->library('crp',array("method" => "candContrib","cid"=> $crp_id,"cycle"=>"2010","output"=>"json"));
// grabs the CRP id from my reference table; have tested and correctly returns string
function _getRefId($id,$type,$src)
{
    switch ($src) {
        case 'crp':
            $field = 'ref_id as id';
            break;
    }
    switch ($type) {
        case 'indiv':
            $this->db->select($field);
            $this->db->where('ref_id',$id);
            $query = $this->db->get('my_ref_table');
            if($query->num_rows() > 0)
            {
                $query = $query->row();
                return $query->id;
            }
            break;
        case 'org':

            break;
    }
}
```

From the way I understand creating custom libraries in CI, this is how I pass an array of parameters to the new instantiation, and it only accepts one array.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to work fine in my setup. Could you possibly be using an object for $crp_id? Can you post the code for the controller as well?

EDIT: I plugged in a stdClass object for $crp_id and got your exact same first error.

EDIT:

```
    switch ($type) {
    case 'indiv':
        $this->db->select($field);
        $this->db->where('ref_id',$id);
        $query = $this->db->get('my_ref_table');
        if($query->num_rows() > 0)
        {
            $query = $query->row();
            var_dump($query->id);
            return $query->id;
        }
        return '';
        break;
    case 'org':
        return '';
        break;
    }
```

Comment: You're totally right that I was using an object instead of an integer for one of the values!!  That fixed the first error, but it's still telling me that the array is an invalid argument for foreach().  What code do you want me to post?

Comment: Glad that partially worked. As for the other error, this library is still working for me with the code you supplied, so I imagine it's something to do with whatever else is in your controller besides just the library loader call. Can you post the controller class and at least the function you're using, if not the whole controller?

Comment: I added the rest of the code that I could think would be relevant.  I'm not even trying to do anything with the class at this point -- I just initialize it in my controller and don't try to call it.  I tried replacing all variables ($crp_id in this latest case) with actual strings, to no avail.  Thanks for all the suggestions!

Comment: Alright, since I don't have access to your database, I have to only theorize. You have it so that if your query returns something, then $crp_id becomes that string. That should be fine. However, you could be getting the error because it doesn't return anything if it finds 0 rows. You should add default return values to maintain consistency of your string outputs in case of different inputs. See my edit above.

Comment: Yeah, it was actually quite helpful. I followed your advice and also deleted a stray line of code that had been uncommented accidentally and that did the trick.  Thanks for all the help!!